# updateOrCreate() gives Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to assign role to user when they attempt. But it gives me this error. I'm using `updateOrCreate()` because I want to use that method later to change user role

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where (`0` = user_id and `1` = =
>   and `2` = 10) limit 1)

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->unsignedInteger("user_id")->index();
     $table->string("role_name");
     $table->foreign("user_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade");
});
```

RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = user::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        "username" => $data["username"],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    if ($user) {
        $model = new Role();
        $model->assignNewbieRole($user->id);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Role model

```
public function assignNewbieRole($id)
{
    $this->updateOrCreate(["user_id","=",$id],["role_name","=","newbie"]);
}
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an associated array instead of individual values:

```
$this->updateOrCreate(["user_id" => $id], ["role_name" => "newbie"]);
```

Comment: Ouch.. How did I do that mistake.. -_-

Comment: I'm guessing you were stuck on the `where` syntax. :-D

Comment: This probably isn't what the OP wants.  The first array should be what to match against, the second array should be the update values.  I assume user_id and role_name should be in separate arguments.

Comment: @Devon You are correct. I had to go read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#other-creation-methods) about it.

Comment: @HasanTıngır make sure you separate the arguments, otherwise this function will only create and never update.

Answer (score 3):

The values have to be set using a associative array where the column name is the key and the value is the value you want to find/insert.

```
$this->updateOrCreate(
    ["user_id" => $id],
    ["role_name" => "newbie"]
);
```